# error React Native CLI uses autolinking for native dependencies, but the following modules are linked manually

Tags: react-native

This error came up after upgrading to React Native 0.60.

I've tried to manually unlink each manually linked dependency using `react-native unlink <dependency>` as suggested in the error message, but the problem still persists.

The error message is as follows:

```
error React Native CLI uses autolinking for native dependencies, but the following modules are linked manually:
  - react-native-admob (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-admob")
  - react-native-facebook-account-kit (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-facebook-account-kit")
  - react-native-fbsdk (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-fbsdk")
  - react-native-gesture-handler (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-gesture-handler")
  - react-native-linear-gradient (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-linear-gradient")
  - react-native-localization (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-localization")
  - react-native-restart (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-restart")
  - react-native-vector-icons (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-vector-icons")
  - react-native-webview (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-webview")
This is likely happening when upgrading React Native from below 0.60 to 0.60 or above. Going forward, you can unlink this dependency via "react-native unlink <dependency>" and it will be included in your app automatically. If a library isn't compatible with autolinking, disregard this message and notify the library maintainers.
Read more about autolinking: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md
```

Comment: refer link https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/671#issuecomment-508903588

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I managed to make the error go away by doing as follows:

1. Create a react-native.config.js file in the root of your project.
2. Update it to something like this:

```
// react-native.config.js
module.exports = {
  dependencies: {
    '<dependency>': {
      platforms: {
        android: null, // disable Android platform, other platforms will still autolink
      },
    },
  },
};
```

[Source](https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/671#issuecomment-508903588)

Comment: Not work for me. error React Native CLI uses autolinking for native dependencies, but the following modules are linked manually:
  - react-native-gesture-handler (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-gesture-handler")
This is likely happening when upgrading React Native from below 0.60 to 0.60 or above. Going forward, you can unlink this dependency via "react-native unlink <dependency>" and it will be
included in your app automatically. If a library isn't compatible with autolinking, disregard this message and notify the library maintainers.

Answer (score 11):

I got this error "React Native CLI uses auto linking for native dependencies, but the following modules are linked manually". I then solve the error by removing those three dependencies, react-native-gesture-handler, react-native-reanimated and react-native-vector-icons from my IOS project with these three commands;

```
react-native unlink react-native-gesture-handler --platforms ios
react-native unlink react-native-reanimated --platforms ios
react-native unlink react-native-vector-icons --platforms ios
```

and then, `$ cd ios` and then `ios/myproject$ pod install` and then `cd ..`and then `myproject$ npx react-native run-ios`

Answer (score 10):

Basically Autolinking is a replacement for react-native link. If you have been using React Native before version 0.60.

> **But you can also disable autolinking for unsupported library**

During the transition period some packages may not support autolinking on certain platforms. To disable autolinking for a package, update your *react-native.config.js*'s dependencies entry to look like this:

```
// react-native.config.js

module.exports = {
  dependencies: {
    'some-unsupported-package': {
      platforms: {
        android: null, // disable Android platform, other platforms will still autolink if provided
      },
    },
  },
};
```

For further clarification follow this link : https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md

Answer (score 3):

just typing this: working for me

1. npx react-native unlink react-native-vector-icons
2. npm remove node_module
3. yarn cache clean
4. yarn install
5. watchman watch-del-all
6. rm -fr $TMPDIR/metro-cache
7. yarn start --clear

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30625741)

Comment: if it presents a solution, then it is answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me removing `node_modules` from your project then running `npm install` to reinstall all the modules.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any perfect answers above. Those are workarounds that do not really address the root cause of the issue.

This issue bugged me a couple of months until I spent a day looking into this today. The issue is caused by two things:

**1. Gradle Files are out of sync in Android Studio.**

Open Android Studio and select the android directory from your React Native project and the Android Studio will auto-sync and build the project. If not, manually select File->Sync Pojrect with Gradle Files. And 9 out 10 times it will run into issues. Either caused by an out of date package still using "compile" instead of "implementation" or some other weird kotlin related issues. You can try these steps

a) Update the package to a newer version or manually replace all lines start with compile to implementation.

b) File->Invalidate Caches /Restart and then select Invalidate and Restart.

c) Build->Clean Project

If none of these above, then Google up each individual issue, and make sure the project syncs and builds successfully.

Now you can try running react-native run-android and see if the unlinking error message still shows. If still persists, do the following.

**2. modules are still loaded**

In Android studio, you will see a .idea directory. Remove the modules.xml (backup first just in case) file under the /.idea. And then do sync and build again.

This should resolve the auto-linking error message.

Answer (score -1):

react-native-config.js

```
module.exports = {
  dependencies: {
    'react-native.config': {
      platforms: {
        android: null, // disable Android platform, other platforms will still autolink if provided
      },
    },
  },
};
```